# Grab frame from video using JavaCV

Tags: java, ffmpeg, video-processing, javacv, xuggler

I am using JavaCV to grab frame from Video.

I can grab if video is in absolute path. But if video is in HTTP than JavaCV throw error.

```
    url = new URL("http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/SampleVideo.mp4");
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    Java2DFrameConverter bimConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();

    FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(inputStream);

    String output = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Downloads\\Test";
    frameGrabber.start();
     Frame frame;  
     double frameRate=frameGrabber.getFrameRate();  
     int imgNum=5;  
     System.out.println("Video has "+frameGrabber.getFrameRate()+" frames and has frame rate of "+frameRate);  
     try {   
       frameGrabber.setFrameNumber(1000);
       frame = frameGrabber.grabKeyFrame();  
       BufferedImage bi = bimConverter.convert(frame);  
       String path = output+File.separator+imgNum+".jpg";  
       ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File(path));
       frameGrabber.stop();   
       frameGrabber.close();
       frameGrabber.flush();                                                                        
     } catch (Exception e) {  
       e.printStackTrace();  
     }
```

Comment: What error does it throw ??

Comment: First thing: JavaCV not even opening the video and error on InputStream.reset() or skip(): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: First of all i want to open the video to grab frames. But i cant even open the video

Comment: What's the size of the video? Could you add the stacktrace into your question?

Comment: 2.1 GB with 120k frames. I am loading video from Microsoft Azure blob

Comment: **(1)** Have you tested on a small file (less than 5mb)? That should help eliminate if the online file's size is the problem. **(2)** Have you tried a smaller frame number to snapshot (eg: frame  #5 instead of frame #1000)? That should help eliminate if the frame #1000 is available when your code tries to `grabKeyFrame()`..  **(3)** Maybe your code setup tries to read the entire file into memory (byte buffer) first before looking for frame #1000, hence the "_OutOfMemoryError_"?

Comment: I have tested with small video. I can open the stream and grab the desired frame. Even while processing small video i got following problem "Could not grab: No AVFormatContext. (Has start() been called?)". But for me i want to process large size video files. If i pass large size video, than library throws "OutOfMemoryError". Is there any way to process large size videos

Comment: To disable buffering, make sure to set the maximumSize to 0 this way: `FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(inputStream, 0);`